# How can I skip the method calls in the std namespace when stepping through a std::function invocation? (Using GDB.)

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb

Stepping through function objects with the debugger can be very confusing if I need to go through a std::function call.

Is it somehow possible to skip these frames?

Comment: You mean like a "step over" command?

Comment: @JohnDibling Yes, some sort of implicit "step over".

Comment: You could set a breakpoint in the function that would be called, and then use continue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I jump into a function held inside std::function in GDB while skipping all the internal implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52442745/how-can-i-jump-into-a-function-held-inside-stdfunction-in-gdb-while-skipping-a)

Comment: I voted the duplicate in this direction, because of the guidance at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/1896169 . The duplicate direction could go the other way.

Answer (score 3):

gdb 7.4 added the skip family of commands for this.

```
(gdb) apropos skip
info skip -- Display the status of skips
set step-mode -- Set mode of the step operation
show step-mode -- Show mode of the step operation
skip -- Ignore a function while stepping
skip delete -- Delete skip entries
skip disable -- Disable skip entries
skip enable -- Enable skip entries
skip file -- Ignore a file while stepping
skip function -- Ignore a function while stepping
```

Comment: This skips a call to std::function at all, instead of going directly to my code.