# How can I jump into a function held inside std::function in GDB while skipping all the internal implementation?

Tags: c++, gdb

Take this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

std::function<int()> getint = []
{
    return 5;
};

void foo(int i)
{
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(getint());
}
```

I'm stopped at a breakpoint at line 17. I want to step into the `getint` function. Using gdb's `step` by default takes me through a bunch of `std::function`'s internal crap that I'm not interested in. If I continue stepping, I will eventually get through to the lambda, but having to do this for every `std::function` call is extremely annoying.

I tried using the `skip` command:

```
skip -rfu ^std::.*
```

but this causes `step` to jump straight into `foo`, completely skipping the lambda inside `std::function`.

Is it possible to configure gdb in a way, where `step` at line 17 would take me straight to the lambda at line 7?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I managed to solve this using a simple python script:

```
import gdb
import re

def stop_handler(event):
    frame_name = gdb.selected_frame().name();
    if re.search("(^std::.*)|(^boost::.*)", frame_name) != None:
        gdb.execute("step")

gdb.events.stop.connect(stop_handler)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me (gdb 8.0.1).  I'm getting strange breaks into __gnu_cxx::__is_null_pointer and __subvdi3, followed by gdb segfault.  So I'd be happy to see any other attempts.

Comment: Works on my side in gdb 8.2 .  It is really fun to watch it in IDE, when it shows dozen of files skipped in a second :))